# How to show form drop down from database in Zend Framework 2.4.0?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to show brands in dropdown. I have the brands in brand table. How to show it in from. I'm Zend beginner. (ZF2.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

This blog post does a very good job explaining how to do what you need: http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/

Doctrine ORM provides a ready-made element [EntitySelect](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/src/DoctrineORMModule/Form/Element/EntitySelect.php) for doing this, but that only helps if you're using Doctrine ORM.  If you're using Doctrine DBAL or Zend\Db you'll need to do it yourself by first querying the database to load a list of your brands then passing that array into the Select form element's `value_options` key.